# Equivalent expression from C in java

Tags: java, c

I am rewriting a program from C to Java and one part that use Bitwise operations.

```
for (int ly = 0; ly < num; ly++){
    char c = sprite[ly];
    for (int lx = 0; lx < 8; lx++) {
        if ((c & (0b10000000 >> lx)) == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        pixels[ly + y][lx + x] = true;
    }
}
```

this is the C code.

I did same in Java. It compiles, runs but this check to see if the bit is on or off is not working proprelly.

How can I check that in java?

Comment: Not a code translation service

Comment: Define "not working". What do you expect the code is supposed to do? Maybe paste the Java code, too, so we can compare.

Comment: You might want to start by optimizing the original C code, since that algorithm is far from ideal.

Comment: the code in java is the same, "not working" I getting a not valid result

Comment: What do you define as "valid"...? How are you not getting this?

Comment: So I will try to explain:
i have this value  "0xf0, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0xf0" in a char array
in binary is gonna be 11110000, 10010000, 10010000, 10010000, 11110000

this part should test "if the pixel is on or off"
for (int lx = 0; lx < 8; lx++) {
   if ((c & (0b10000000 >> lx)) == 0)  {
      continue;
}...
so after that loop i will hava a matrix of boolean to know what i have to render
this first vales is a 0
****
*   *
*   *
*   * 
**** i am getting   

****
*   *
*   *
****  with one line less and the other chars go to the continue; instruction

Answer (score 1):

That snippet, as posted is perfectly valid Java code and does the same thing in Java, roughly speaking, as it would in C. The definitions of what `int` and `char` are are slightly different (for example, in java, an `int` is always a 32-bit signed integer, but in C it depends on the architecture). But the basics are all the same.

Comment: Yes is compiling and running but the result is not the expected, Do you think is because of the types definitions ?

Comment: @HudsonSchumaker Define inputs, expected output and actual output